# reference to undefined property "{!$RemoteAction"

Tags: visualforce, pdf, remote-action, reference

**This is my Javascript**

```
$scope.getRemoteCase = function() {

    var caseID = [];
    var caseID = $scope.caseIdInfo;
    alert("caseID" + caseID);
    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
        '{!$RemoteAction.GeneratePDF_VFC.getCase}',
        caseID,
        function(result, event) {
            console.log(result);
            window.open(result, "_blank");
        }, {
            escape: true
        }
    );
}
```

**My Visual page code**

```
<button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral"
        ng-click="getRemoteCase()" id="custPrint">{!$Label.Print}
</button>
```

If I print the pdf the console shows the following error

**reference to undefined property "{!$RemoteAction"**

The getRemotecase fuction is called but

```
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
        '{!$RemoteAction.GeneratePDF_VFC.getCase}',
```

is not navigating the **GeneratePDF_VFC** file

Comment: Is you javascript perchance in a static resource?. If so, that merge field won't work.

Comment: Also, if you have not annotated your controller method with `@RemoteAction` then that call won't work either...

Comment: Hello Caspar Harmer, thank you for your answer ,Yes its static resoure and How to annotated my controller method with @RemoteAction

Comment: declare the variable in your vf page and use it in the static resource ill add as answer soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Visualforce merge fields are evaluated server-side, static resources containing merge fields won't be evaluated.

To get around this, declare your javascript in the VisualForce page:

```
var controllerActionName = '{!$RemoteAction.GeneratePDF_VFC.getCase}';
```

Then in your static resource, use this var:

```
 Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
    controllerActionName,
    caseID,
    function(result, event) {}, 
    {escape: true}
 );
```

You'll need to do this for any merge fields that you have in the static resource.